# Why typeahead in angular-tags is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead

I have the following code.

```
<form ng-controller="emailViewController">
   <tags options="{addable: true}" placeholder="To" typeahead-options="typeaheadOpts" data-model="information.select" data-src="toPerson as toPerson for toPerson in to" style="width:95%;"></tags>
</form>
```

`emailViewController.js`

```
'use strict';

var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService,
                                    $scope,$filter) {

    var url = 'app/mock/emails.json';
    fetchDataService.getContent(url)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.emails = response.data;
            $scope.to = [];

            angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key) {
               $scope.to.push(key.to);
            });
        });

      $scope.to = ["John"];
};
angular.module('iisEmail')
    .controller ('emailViewController',
    ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', emailViewController]);
}());
```

I have the following questions:

1) The `$scope.to` variable in the `then` callback contains an array like so `["America","Australia","Canada","Dubai"]`. After the callback function, I am redefining the value of `$scope.to` to be `["John"]`. However, when I type `a` in the `tag` element, I still see `typeahead` suggesting me to choose `America` or `Australia`. When I type `j`, `John` doesn't appear as an option. What is causing this behavior?

Just to avoid confusion, I want to make it clear that, my app is working perfectly. I just want to understand this behavior because I don't want my app breaking in the future.

2) When I change the code as follows, nothing appears as suggestions from `typeahead`

`emailViewController.js`

```
   'use strict';

    var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService,
                                        $scope,$filter) {

        var url = 'app/mock/emails.json';
        fetchDataService.getContent(url)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.emails = response.data;
                $scope.to = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key) {
                   $scope.to.push(key.to);
                });
            });
    };
    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('emailViewController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', emailViewController]);
}());
```

So, removing `$scope.to = ["John"]` breaks the code. Does anyone have ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $http service runs the request asynchronously and returns you a promise.

The execution order of your code is this.

```
fetchDataService.getContent(url)
```

then it continues with the rest of the function

```
 $scope.to = ["John"];
```

then then the request completes and the promise resolves

```
    .then(function(response){
            $scope.emails = response.data;
            $scope.to = [];

            angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key) {
               $scope.to.push(key.to);
            });
        });
```

Removing the $scope.to = ["John"] means the $scope.to is undefined, and that's most likely why the typeahead fails. You are iterating on undefined.

Try doing this instead:

```
'use strict';

var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService,
                                $scope,$filter) {

var url = 'app/mock/emails.json';
$scope.to = [];
fetchDataService.getContent(url)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.emails = response.data;

        angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key) {
           $scope.to.push(key.to);
        });
    });


};
angular.module('iisEmail')
    .controller ('emailViewController',
    ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', emailViewController]);
}());
```

That way you initialize the **to** array as an empty list, and later when the http request is done you get the list of elements from the server.

Also check out angular **$q** for more info about promises in angular.